# getRecord fails intermittently in simple LWCs

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm finding that using `getRecord` fails intermittently - I've seen this in multiple orgs now and I'm not sure if it's something I'm doing wrong or if there is a bug in the wire service. Here is a simple example to reproduce:

```js
import { LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import PROFILE_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.Profile.Name';

export default class TestUserWire extends LightningElement {

    @track profileName;
    @track error;

    // // User Details
    @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: USER_ID,
        fields: [PROFILE_NAME_FIELD]
    }) wireFieldSetUser({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            // this.profileName = data.fields.Profile.value.fields.Name.value;
            this.profileName = data.fields.Profile.displayValue;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.profileName = undefined;
        }
    }

}
```

Then in the template:

```
<template>
    Profile: {profileName}
</template>
```

Add this component (and nothing else) to a Record Lightning Page (e.g. for an Account). Now, open an Account and you'll see "Profile: System Administrator", open a new Account (without triggering a page refresh - i.e. by clicking the dropdown arrow on the Accounts tab and selecting a recently opened Account) and you will see the same thing. Now - keep switching between Accounts. Eventually (e.g. after 10-20 switches between Accounts) it will fail and you will get "Profile:    ". There are no errors in the console.

The issue is more prominent in more complicated pages where there are multiple LWCs on one page, all using `getRecord`.

Am I doing something wrong? When I instead use an Apex Wire call the problem goes away.

**EDIT - VIDEO**

Using simplified example getting User FirstName rather than Profile. At the end of the video the GetRecord fails.

https://youtu.be/emRGiVYgZL0

Comment: Have you try something like this? : `this.profileName = data.fields.Profile.Name.value; `

Comment: That's the thing - it doesn't matter which field. I could for example instead be requesting the FirstName field on the User record. It will return that, but after 20 or so switches, it fails - what field you're querying doesn't matter. Perhaps it'll help if I do a video.